# Vector losing data after insertion

Tags: c++, vector, storing-data

Here's the problem:
I have a class named 'state' that stores a vector of int. In my program, I'm creating a vector of state but after that when I try to get the values of the vector of int it seems like it is just empty. I created a .cpp file to test this out:

state.h:

```
#ifndef STATE_H 
#define STATE_H

#include <vector>

class state {
    public:
        std::vector<int> vectorstate;
        ~state(); 
        state(); 
        state(state &sta); 
        state(const state &sta); 
        state & operator= (const state &sta);
        bool operator==(const state &sta) const;
};

#endif
```

state.cpp:

```
#include "state.h"
using namespace std;

state::~state(){
}

state::state(){
} 

state::state(state &est){
    for(int i=0;i<vectorstate.size();i++)
        vectorstate[i] = est.vectorstate[i];
}

state::state(const state &est){
    for(int i=0;i<vectorstate.size();i++)
        vectorstate[i] = est.vectorstate[i];
}

state & state::operator= (const state &est) {
    if (this == &est) return *this;
    for(int i=0;i<vectorstate.size();i++)
        vectorstate[i] = est.vectorstate[i];
    return *this;
}

bool state::operator==(const state &est) const {
    for(int i=0;i<vectorstate.size();i++)
        if(vectorstate[i] != est.vectorstate[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

main.cpp (for tests purpose):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "state.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    state before, after;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        before.vectorstate.push_back(i);
    for(int i=0;i<before.vectorstate.size();i++)
        cout << before.vectorstate[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    for(int i=3;i<12;i++)
        after.vectorstate.push_back(i);
    for(int i=0;i<after.vectorstate.size();i++)
        cout << after.vectorstate[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    vector<state> vetor;
    vetor.push_back(before);
    vetor.push_back(after);
    for(int i=0;i<vetor[0].vectorstate.size();i++)
        cout << vetor[0].vectorstate[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vetor[1].vectorstate.size();i++)
        cout << vetor[1].vectorstate[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    state aux;
    aux = vetor.front();
    for(int i=0;i<aux.vectorstate.size();i++)
        cout << aux.vectorstate[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

And this output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV5LA.jpg

(Sorry about the link, I couldn't post the image here, cause of reputation I guess).

So as you can see, I tried in different ways to access this int vector but it gave me no result, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Please create a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Please copy and paste the output into the question, for when that link dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your implementation of copy constructor and assignment operator.

```
state & state::operator= (const state &est) {
    if (this == &est) return *this;
    for(int i=0;i<vectorstate.size();i++)
        vectorstate[i] = est.vectorstate[i];
    return *this;
}
```

If `vectorstate` of `this` is currently empty, then `vectorstate.size()` will return `0` and the contents of the for loop will never be executed. Inside your copy constructors and assignment operator, make sure you copy the complete vector (`std::vector` has a working copy constructor).

Or better yet, don't implement them and let the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code a "little" and voila:

### state.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "state.h"

using namespace std;
state::state() {}
state::state(const state &est) : vectorstate(est.vectorstate) {}
state & state::operator= (const state &est) {
  if (this == &est) return *this;
  vectorstate.resize(est.vectorstate.size());
  std::copy(est.vectorstate.begin(), est.vectorstate.end(), vectorstate.begin());
  return *this;
}
bool state::operator==(const state &est) const { return est.vectorstate == vectorstate; }
```

### state.h

```
    #ifndef STATE_H 
    #define STATE_H

    #include <vector>

    struct state {
      std::vector<int> vectorstate;
      state();
      state(const state &sta);
      state & operator=(const state &sta);
      bool operator==(const state &sta) const;
    };
    #endif
```

### **Reasons/Bugs:**

1. You were messing things in your copy constructor. `vectorstate` is empty once the copy constructor is evoked so can't copy elements by subscript.
2. You were messing things in your assignment operator. You have first to resize the vector and then copy the elements of the other object.
3. In your equality operator applying `==` operator on the vectors is sufficient.